# Check if a dependency is installable (requirable) according to my composer.json

Tags: php, composer-php

I've a problem, I just want to know if a certain package is installable inside my project that uses composer. But without run composer require. Is this possible?

For example, .. a sort og

```
composer require some/package --something
```

where `something` is a configuration that eventually will output

```
yes you can
```

I need, finally, to know if a requirement could be resolved or no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an obvious solution: Have your current files checked into version control (including `composer.json` and `composer.lock`) and then require the package you want to test.

The not so obvious solution:

```
composer prohibits some/package 1.2.3
```

You'd have to give the exact version you intend to install in order to make the command return meaningful output. Note that you will not really get an output if your package is installable.

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#prohibits for some more details.